# Django: set DEBUG = False causes Server Error (500)

Tags: python, django, debugging, django-views, django-templates

the templats work when DEBUG = True but change to False gives Server Error (500)
i used django 3.2.8

This is views.py file

```
def test(request):
context = {}
if request.method == "POST":
    uploaded_file = request.FILES['document']
    print(uploaded_file)
    if uploaded_file.name.endswith('.csv'):
        #save file in media folder
        savefile = FileSystemStorage()
        name = savefile.save(uploaded_file.name, uploaded_file) #name of the file
        #know where to save file
        d = os.getcwd() #current directory of the project
        file_directory = d + '\media\\' + name
        readfile(file_directory)
        return redirect(results)
    else:
         messages.warning(request, 'File was not uploaded. Please use csv or xlsx file extension!')

return render(request, 'test.html', {})
```

#project.csv
def readfile(filename):
global rows, columns, data, my_file, missing_values, mydict, dhead, dtail, dinfo, ddesc, dcor, graph, dheat

```
my_file = pd.read_csv(filename, engine='python', index_col = False, sep='[: ; , | -]', error_bad_lines=False)
data = pd.DataFrame(data=my_file)
#my_file= read_file(filename)
```

## data = pd.DataFrame(data=my_file)

```
mydict = {

    
    "data ": data.to_html(),
    
}

#rows and columns
rows = len(data.axes[0])
columns = len(data.axes[1])

#find missing data
missingsings = ['?','0','--']
null_data = data[data.isnull().any(axis=1)]
missing_values = len(null_data)
```

def results(request):

```
    message = 'I found ' +  str(rows) + ' rows and ' + str(columns) + ' columns. Missing data are: ' + str(missing_values)
    #message = info
    messages.warning(request, message)

    return render(request, 'results.html', context = mydict)
```

This is settings.py file

```
# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = env('secret_key')

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!

DEBUG = False

ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['*']


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'widget_tweaks',
    'dtest',
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'datestproject.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'datestproject.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
        'NAME': 'dbtest',
        'USER': 'postgres',
        'PASSWORD':'850636',
        'HOST': 'localhost',
        'PORT': '5432',
    }
}


# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'Asia/Riyadh'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = '/static/'

STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'),
]

MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'





# Default primary key field type
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/settings/#default-auto-field

DEFAULT_AUTO_FIELD = 'django.db.models.BigAutoField'

# Email Settings

EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend'
EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.gmail.com'
EMAIL_PORT = '587'
EMAIL_HOST_USER = env('email_user')
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = env('email_pass')
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
EMAIL_USE_SSL = False
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. [HTTP 500](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes#5xx_server_errors) is a generic server-side error message. On its own it doesn't tell us anything useful. Any time you see this your first step should be to check your error logs for more detail.

Answer (score 1):

Django does not support file serving in production ([have a look here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/howto/static-files/#serving-files-uploaded-by-a-user-during-development)).
If you want to save and serve files in production with  `debug=False` try to switch to another [storage backend](https://django-storages.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html).

Comment: thanks for response.. the files save in media folder, some gives the result but usually no result Server Error (500). added + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT) but same problem :(

Comment: As stated in the documentation, the helper function "+ static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT) " works only in debug mode. Also check this answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59504624/15353043

Answer (score 0):

You can debug the error by this setting:

```
DEBUG_PROPAGATE_EXCEPTIONS = True
```

See the reference here:- https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/settings/#debug-propagate-exceptions